# Shifting beyond max limit yielding a periodic sequence

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

I have written the following code and executed it on CodeBlocks IDE:

```
main()
{
 unsigned char num=1;
 unsigned char i=0;

 for(i=0;i<255;i++)
 {
  printf("%d\n",num>>i);
 }
}
```

Output:
    1,0,0,..(31 0's),1,0..(31 0's)

Any value for num generates a periodic sequence.

I know shifting beyond limit(mem size for num) is undefined behavior,but why is it periodic?

A periodic sequence is generated even if you left shift

Comment: "I know shifting beyond limit(mem size for num) is undefined behavior,but why is it periodic?" Don't you think your statement is contradictory?

Comment: Undefined= No specific universal logic, Periodic= I can place a logic saying when it will repeat

Comment: Because some assember 32bit shift instructions accept only 5 bits for the right operant, so `num>>i` will be `num>>(i&0x1F)`.

Comment: It kind of looks like a rotate rather than a shift

Comment: Try it on a few different CPU families.

Comment: I used it on an online compiler as well. Its periodic

Comment: When you left shift and print, the value is promoted to a 32 bit value and printed. Nonetheless, still periodic

Comment: And the online compiler used the exact same CPU family that all your tests were on. The CPU family that happens to have shift instructions that truncate the amount you shift by to 5 bits as @mch already told you. Undefined behavior in this case is there so that the compiler can generate efficient code (not adding checks if you shift too much before every shift).

Comment: @mch- why dont you suggest it as an answer? I feel thats the reason

Answer (score 4):

It's allowed to be periodic since that's a possible manifestation of undefined behaviour.

Don't rely on it being that.

Comment: I've just tried it on mine. The compiler just tried to eat my cat. (Although I am now thinking of switching compiler vendors ;-) )

Comment: Wat was ur output?

Comment: A seemingly irrational dive for the catflap.